# Handling multiple date formats in Automapper

Tags: automapper

For example, suppose we have a source type of:

```
public class Source
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

And we would like to map it to:

```
public class Destination
{
    public DateTime Value1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Value2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

Each Value is converted using a different date format.

```
CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeConverter1());
CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeConverter2());
CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeConverter3());

CreateMap<DateTime, string>().ConvertUsing(dt => dt.ToString(DateStringAttribute.DateFormatString1));
CreateMap<DateTime, string>().ConvertUsing(dt => dt.ToString(DateStringAttribute.DateFormatString2));
CreateMap<DateTime, string>().ConvertUsing(dt => dt.ToString(DateStringAttribute.DateFormatString3));
```

How can I get the correct format used (going both ways) when I can only specify string and DateTime?
Can I somehow access the property name so I can select the appropriate conversion format?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-converters.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it but this seemed to work.

```
CreateMap<Destination, Source>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Value1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>src.Value1.HasValue?src.Value1.Value.ToString(DateStringAttribute.DateFormat1):""))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Value2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>src.Value2.HasValue?src.Value2.Value.ToString(DateStringAttribute.DateFormat2):""))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Value3, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>src.Value3.HasValue?src.Value3.Value.ToString(DateStringAttribute.DateFormat3):""))
.ReverseMap();
```

Comment: That's the reason value converters exist. To enable reuse.

Comment: Thanks Lucian. I will check out value converters.